# Как при нажатии на **конкретный плюс** добавить количество в **конкретном** элементе?

Tags: javascript

Есть элементы  **"+ 0 -"** их несколько . Как при нажатии на **конкретный плюс** добавить количество в **конкретном** элементе?
есть ссылка там набросал пример. очень долго мучаюсь с этой проблемой.
https://jsfiddle.net/gc670r4j/6/

```js
var plus = document.querySelectorAll('.dishes__num-plus');
var minus = document.querySelectorAll('.dishes__num-minus');
var curr = document.querySelectorAll('.dishes__num-current');
    
    
    for(var i = 0 ; i<plus.length;i++){
            
        plus[i].onclick = function(){
            for(var i = 0 ; i<curr.length;i++){
             curr[i].innerHTML++;
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
.dishes__item-num{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
.dishes__num-minus{
    width: 16px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #333333;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dishes__num-current{
    margin: 0 20px;
    color: #F22C2C;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.dishes__num-plus{
    background: #F22C2C;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 16px;
    height: 4px;
}
.dishes__num-plus:after {
    content: "";
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 16px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #F22C2C;
}
```

```html
<div class="dishes__item-num">
  <div class="dishes__num-minus"></div>
  <div class="dishes__num-current">0</div>
  <div class="dishes__num-plus"></div>
</div>
<div class="dishes__item-num">
  <div class="dishes__num-minus"></div>
  <div class="dishes__num-current">0</div>
  <div class="dishes__num-plus"></div>
</div>
<div class="dishes__item-num">
  <div class="dishes__num-minus"></div>
  <div class="dishes__num-current">0</div>
  <div class="dishes__num-plus"></div>
</div>
<div class="dishes__item-num">
  <div class="dishes__num-minus"></div>
  <div class="dishes__num-current">0</div>
  <div class="dishes__num-plus"></div>
</div>
<div class="dishes__item-num">
  <div class="dishes__num-minus"></div>
  <div class="dishes__num-current">0</div>
  <div class="dishes__num-plus"></div>
</div>
<div class="dishes__item-num">
  <div class="dishes__num-minus"></div>
  <div class="dishes__num-current">0</div>
  <div class="dishes__num-plus"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте обработчик к родителю этих блоков, используя делегирование:

```js
document.querySelector('.wrap').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let oClasses = e.target.classList;
  let oCurrent = e.target.parentElement.querySelector('.dishes__num-current');
  if (oClasses.contains('dishes__num-minus')) {
    oCurrent.innerHTML = parseInt(oCurrent.innerHTML) - 1;
  } else if (oClasses.contains('dishes__num-plus')) {
    oCurrent.innerHTML = parseInt(oCurrent.innerHTML) + 1;
  };
});
```

```css
.dishes__item-num {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.dishes__num-minus {
  width: 16px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #333333;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dishes__num-current {
  margin: 0 20px;
  color: #F22C2C;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dishes__num-plus {
  background: #F22C2C;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 16px;
  height: 4px;
}

.dishes__num-plus:after {
  content: "";
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 4px;
  background: #F22C2C;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="dishes__item-num">
    <div class="dishes__num-minus"></div>
    <div class="dishes__num-current">0</div>
    <div class="dishes__num-plus"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dishes__item-num">
    <div class="dishes__num-minus"></div>
    <div class="dishes__num-current">0</div>
    <div class="dishes__num-plus"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dishes__item-num">
    <div class="dishes__num-minus"></div>
    <div class="dishes__num-current">0</div>
    <div class="dishes__num-plus"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dishes__item-num">
    <div class="dishes__num-minus"></div>
    <div class="dishes__num-current">0</div>
    <div class="dishes__num-plus"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dishes__item-num">
    <div class="dishes__num-minus"></div>
    <div class="dishes__num-current">0</div>
    <div class="dishes__num-plus"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="dishes__item-num">
    <div class="dishes__num-minus"></div>
    <div class="dishes__num-current">0</div>
    <div class="dishes__num-plus"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: прямо в точку, спасибо огромное)